# Is it any way to extend the default camera in android?

Tags: android, camera

I have been thinking in implementing some feature only for the camera in android, do you know if it is possible?

I mean, overriding the behaviour of the default camera, not opening a new one from my app, like implementing a plugin that attaches to the camera app.

Investigating I only found that you can actually implement a layer, on top of the camera, to add buttons, but you need to launch it from your app, which is what I don't want.

Thanks!!!

Comment: have you gone through :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501651/is-it-possible-to-extend-the-android-camera-class

Comment: @MOSO yes and it's not what I'm looking for :(

Comment: I also have a similar requirement. Google lens has created a button in the default camera app... They can do because they are owners of Android. What about poor developers like us? How do we do something like that? I don't want to develop a new app.